# Подскажите в чем ошибка, почему не могу извлечь данные?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Использую библиотеки retrofit. У меня структура JSON вот такая:

```
 "routes":[
  {
     "platforms":[
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"АТБ-Містечко",
           "lat":50.2107736547029,
           "lng":30.3174322843552,
           "id":1022549,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"пр.Лесі Українки, 15 ",
           "lat":50.1974241245373,
           "lng":30.2944350242615,
           "id":1022542,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Столичка",
           "lat":50.216073975587,
           "lng":30.3178024291992,
           "id":1022543,
           "quantity":3
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Солнечная",
           "lat":50.1883300230983,
           "lng":30.2941560745239,
           "id":1022544,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Володимирська,13",
           "lat":50.1747131083508,
           "lng":30.3193259239197,
           "id":1022545,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Володимирька, 28 (Корунд)",
           "lat":50.1733834992561,
           "lng":30.3227108716965,
           "id":1022546,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Фуршет",
           "lat":50.1795055782639,
           "lng":30.3133499622345,
           "id":1022547,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Набережна",
           "lat":50.1800174337311,
           "lng":30.3084254264832,
           "id":1022548,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Військове .Містечко",
           "lat":50.2120369970609,
           "lng":30.3167670965195,
           "id":1022550,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"вул.Грушевського,25",
           "lat":50.180299123662,
           "lng":30.3108340501785,
           "id":1022551,
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "estimated_fill":1.0,
           "volume":1.100,
           "address":"Іванковичі",
           "lat":50.2786446089967,
           "lng":30.4251337051392,
           "id":1022552,
           "quantity":2
        }
     ],
     "num":"01.05 - Смаколики",
     "id":1022554,
     "itinerary":""
  }
],
"success":true
```

Вот мой интерфес :

```
@Headers({("X-Signature: reserved"),("Content-Type: text/x-json")})
@POST("get_routes")
Call <MyRoutes> getRoutes(@Body Map<String, String> id);
```

Вот мой retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://gps.alematics.com/") // Адрес сервера/
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // говорим ретрофиту что для сериализации необходимо использовать GSON
            .build();
jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
```

Вот так звоню:

```
public void getRouteList() {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("device_id", "1789fa18ad90ba55");
    Call<MyRoutes> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getRoutes(parameters);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyRoutes> () {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyRoutes> call, Response<MyRoutes> response) {

 List<MyRoutes>rout=Collections.singletonList(response.body());
           
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("asd", "no" + response.errorBody());
                return;
            } else {
                EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                Log.d("asd", "" + myRoutes.getRoutes());
              

                    }
                


                }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyRoutes>  call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("asd", "error");
        }
    });
```

MyRoutes:

```
 @SerializedName("routes")
    @Expose
    private List routes = null;
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;

    public List getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setRoutes(List routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
```

Routes:

```
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Route {

@SerializedName("platforms")
@Expose
private List<Platform> platforms = null;
@SerializedName("num")
@Expose
private String num;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("itinerary")
@Expose
private String itinerary;

public List<Platform> getPlatforms() {
    return platforms;
}

public void setPlatforms(List<Platform> platforms) {
    this.platforms = platforms;
}

public String getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(String num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getItinerary() {
    return itinerary;
}

public void setItinerary(String itinerary) {
    this.itinerary = itinerary;
}
```

Platforms:

```
 @Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
    public class Platform {
        @SerializedName("estimated_fill")
        @Expose
        private Float estimatedFill;
        @SerializedName("volume")
        @Expose
        private Float volume;
        @SerializedName("address")
        @Expose
        private String address;
        @SerializedName("lat")
        @Expose
        private Float lat;
        @SerializedName("lng")
        @Expose
        private Float lng;
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private Integer id;
        @SerializedName("quantity")
        @Expose
        private Integer quantity;

        public Float getEstimatedFill() {
            return estimatedFill;
        }

        public void setEstimatedFill(Float estimatedFill) {
            this.estimatedFill = estimatedFill;
        }

        public Float getVolume() {
            return volume;
        }

        public void setVolume(Float volume) {
            this.volume = volume;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public Float getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(Float lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public Float getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(Float lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Integer getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
```

Comment: Вот он вам подскажет: https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo

Comment: вы уже столько мучаетесь с этим вопросом... покажеите уже полную URL к API и вам просто напишут код

Comment: Так и сделаю)))

Comment: приложите код как обрабатываете json и как формируются массивы данных на вашей стороне

Comment: Добавил все что есть)))

Comment: так и что вам в итоге нужно? вопрос только в том как правильно с json работать и все?

Comment: То что я скинул, оно не работает и я не понимаю в чем проблема. Я не могу получить отдельные элементы. Вроде все логично и понятно, но что то я не понимаю до конца((Если теперь извлекать данные с такой структуры, получаю null с любого списка. [Route{null}, Route{null}, Route{null}, Route{null}, Route{null}, Route{null}, Route{null}]

Comment: Все! Разобрался! Не правильно использовал работу с массивами, которые были в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось и решило мою проблему:

```
List<Route> trt = response.body().getRoutes();
                for(Route rtr : trt){
                   List<Platform> pl = rtr.getPlatforms();
                    for(Platform plt : pl){
                        Log.d("asd", "" +   plt.getLng());
                        String lon = String.valueOf(plt.getLng());
                        editText.setText("" + lon);
                    }
```